# how do i give the same positions to student with the same mark

Tags: java

i have tried  several times but am still not getting,this is my first java code. the user enters the student details such as name, id and marks for subject and then displays in GUI, the student result in descending order with position such as 1st,2nd etc. but the problem now is that the student with the same mark should have the same position but mine just does the opposite . Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public class Student  {

    private String id,sn,ln;

    private double eng,math,social,science;


    public Student(){

    }     
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public void setSn(String s){
        this.sn=s;
    }
    public void setLn(String s){
        this.ln=s;
    }
    public void setEng(double en){
        this.eng=en;
    }       
    public void setMath(double ma){
        this.math=ma;  
    } 
    public void setSocial(double so){
        this.social=so;
    } 
    public void setScience(double sc){
        this.science=sc;
    }   
  public String getSid(){
     return id;
  }  
  public String getSname(){
     return sn;
  }          
  public String getLname(){
     return ln;
  }        
  public double getEng(){
            return eng;
  }
  public double getMath(){
      return math;
  }
  public double getSocial(){
      return social;
  }
  public double getScience(){
      return science;
  }      

  public double getAverage(){
      return (getEng()+getMath()+getSocial()+getScience())/4.0;
  }

  public double getTotalMark(){
     return    getEng()+getMath()+getSocial()+getScience();
 }
    int position;

 public String getPosition(int x){
     position=x;
      switch (position){   
     case 1:
          case 21:
               case 31:
                    case 41:            
      return position+"st";
          case 2:
               case 22:
                    case 32:
                         case 42:
      return position+"nd";
               case 3:
                   case 23:
                       case 33:
                           case 43:
      return position+"rd";
     default:  
       return position +"th";
 }
 }

     public String header(){
             // returns the header of the ressult
        return "STUDENT ID\t STUDENT NAME  \t ENGLISH \t MATH \t SOCIAL \t SCIENCE "
                + "\t TOTALMARK \t AVERAGE  \t POSITIONS\n";

          }
            @Override
          public String toString(){
                // display all the values of the student 
          return getSid()+"\t\t"+getSname()+" "+getLname()+
                  "  \t\t"+getEng()+"\t"+getMath()+"\t "+getSocial()+
                  "\t"+getScience()+"\t"+getTotalMark()+
                  "\t\t"+getAverage();
          }
```

this is my sort method. because average is double,student with 55.0 is rated higher than one with 55.5. i get error if i try to change the it to double

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class sortAverage implements Comparator <Student> {

      @Override
              public int compare(Student s1,Student s2){

            return (int) (s2.getAverage()-s1.getAverage());

      }
}
```

this is where i called my code

```
public class thehandler implements ActionListener{
       @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){

                 Student student=new Student();

          if(ev.getSource()==addData){

              if(listof.size() <= 4){

              try{   

                  student.setEng(Double.parseDouble(eng.getText().toString()));
                  student.setScience(Double.parseDouble(sci.getText().toString()));
                  student.setSocial(Double.parseDouble(soc.getText().toString()));
                  student.setMath(Double.parseDouble(math.getText().toString()));}
              catch(Exception e){

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "one or more of the subject fields contains invalid inputs,PLEASE NUMBER REQUIRED, please check it", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

           return;
      }
                  student.setId(sidInput.getText().toString());
                  student.setSn(snameInput.getText().toString());
                  student.setLn(lnameInput.getText().toString());

                  listof.add(student);

                  sidInput.setText("");
                  snameInput.setText("");
                  lnameInput.setText("");
                  eng.setText("");
                  math.setText("");
                  soc.setText("");
                  sci.setText("");
                 }else{

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The maximum Number of Student that can be added is 50 ",
                           "ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


                   return;
              }   

                Collections.sort(listof, new sortAverage());

             }
             else if(ev.getSource()==viewData){

                 display.setText(student.header());

                display.setFont(new Font("serif",Font.BOLD,16));


               int x=0;

               for(Student of:listof){
                  x++; 

              display.append(of.toString()+"\r\t"+of.getPosition(x)+"\r\n");

            }


             }

          }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting invalid sorting results because of incorrect comparison of `double` values in `sortAverage` class. Casting `double` to `int` is unacceptable since it ignores decimal part. E.g.

```
(int) (55.5-55.0)
```

will be 0 instead of 0.5, and two values will be equal.
Use `Double.compare()` method for this:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class sortAverage implements Comparator <Student> {

  @Override
          public int compare(Student s1,Student s2)
  {
          return Double.compare(s2.getAverage(),s1.getAverage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is working perfectly now. Now I can finally move on to my next project.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your last `for` loop to smth like following:

```
int x=0;
Student lastStudent = null;
for (Student of:listof) {
    if (lastStudent == null || Double.compare(of.getAverage(), lastStudent.getAverage()) != 0) {
        x++;
    }
    display.append(of.toString()+"\r\t"+of.getPosition(x)+"\r\n");
    lastStudent = of;
}
```

And use `Double.compare(s1.getAverage(), s2.getAverage())` instead of simply subtracting values in your `Comparator` as it more safe to rounding errors.

Comment: It worked well . Now students with same marks are positioned equally. Thanks